# Custom shape for RelativeLayout Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-custom-view

Is it possible to create custom shape like image below on relativelayout ?

i've tried with this code :

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    int w = this.getWidth() - (this.getWidth()/4);
    int w2 = this.getWidth() - (this.getWidth()/6);
    int h = this.getHeight();
    Point a = new Point(0, 0);
    Point b = new Point(w, 0);
    Point c = new Point(w2, h);
    Point d = new Point(0, h);

    Path path = new Path();
    path.moveTo(a.x, a.y);
    path.lineTo(b.x, b.y);
    path.lineTo(c.x, c.y);
    path.lineTo(d.x, d.y);
    path.lineTo(a.x, a.y);
    path.close();

    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.drawPath(path, p);

    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

But it is not working. Any idea ?

[image: Custom Shape]

Comment: is it drawing anything ?

Comment: yea .. it's drawing the white part .. what i need is the grey part and the white transparant ? is it possible @Blackbelt

Comment: why don't you use an image?

Comment: it will be a last option i take @OsamaAftab .. i try to change a path but whatever i change .. it only draw the white part